# Cоюз или вводное слово?

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, чем является слово "значит" и нужна ли запятая?

> Если про тебя идут слухи (,) значит(,) ты личность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, в данном примере ЗНАЧИТ - вводное слово со значением "следовательно". Запятая нужна.
Кроме того, это слово находится между частями сложноподчинённого предложения, а в этом случае запятая тоже ставится. 
 Но слово ЗНАЧИТ может быть средством связи между подлежащим и сказуемым, ср.: Жить - значит бороться. А в предложениях типа "Всё это значит гораздо больше, чем ты думаешь" оно играет роль сказуемого и запятыми не выделяется. В двух последних примерах ЗНАЧИТ синонимично ОЗНАЧАЕТ.

```
Дополняю ответ:
```

В оформлении связи между словами и предложениями принимают участие ***корреляты*** - позиционно **не смыкающиеся с союзом** ***служебные элементы***, образующие вместе с ним двухместное союзное соединение. Различаются 1) семантически не специализированные корреляты ***то, так*** (если – ***то***, если – **так**), указывающие только на синтаксическую связь предложений, и 2) ***специализированные корреляты***: тогда, тут (разг.), ***значит***, знать (прост.), следовательно, стало быть (прост.), выходит (прост.). И те и другие могут употребляться совместно, образуя составной коррелят, в рамках которого ***компонент со специализированным значением*** занимает ***позицию уточнителя***: (если) – то + тогда; (если) – то + значит; (поскольку) – то + следовательно; (раз) – то + стало быть. [Плюсы мои - Е.К.]
Корреляты могут осуществлять **связующую функцию** и самостоятельно, ***без участия союза***: Послушать вас, так мы находимся вне человечества (Тург.); Прикажут – тут уж ничего не поделаешь (разг. речь).(http://rusgram.narod.ru/1669-1688.html)

Итак, слово ЗНАЧИТ - не союз, а служебный элемент,  который ***вместе с союзом*** может  образовать  "союзное соединение".

Всё о сочетании "если...значит":
§ 3017,3018.(http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5315&0a0=1831#3017)

**Прочитайте, пожалуйста. ***Это нечто***... Спасибо автору за вопрос! Очень интересный и, как оказалось, по-настоящему сложный. Вопрос, который заставил серьёзно изучить тему. Она оказалась очень глубокой.**

Comment: Мне казалось, что если можно заменить на "следовательно", то слово как раз таки будет выполнять функцию союза.Но не в этом все соль, простите.
 Разве "значит" не может быть частью двойного союза «если... значит» ?

Answer (score 0):

Слово **значит** является вводным и обособляется, если оно синонимично словам *следовательно*, *стало быть*. (По Розенталю). Значит, в Вашем примере это вводное слово обсобляется.

> Дополняю ответ

Екатерина, спасибо за ссылку. Про коррелят поняла, только не поняла, ставится ли запятая. 
§ 3018. ...Такие предложения сообщают об основании (придаточная часть), достаточном для вывода, умозаключения (главная часть):   **И если я себе нравлюсь - значит пел хорошо** (К. Коровин); Если я это сказал, значит я увлекся (Эренб.); Если Филипп Петрович так поступил, значит иного выхода не было (Фад.); Если сразу не приехал, значит, не так уж стремился к сыну (Симон.). 
 § 3019. ...  Характерный признак таких предложений - двузначность: та часть, которая представлена говорящим как умозаключение (вывод, следствие), фактически называет реальную причину того, о чем сообщается в части, оформленной условным союзом: **Если я себе нравлюсь (довод) - значит, пел хорошо (вывод)** ((я себе нравлюсь, потому что я пел хорошо)). Направление обусловленности, возникающее в результате подобного преобразования, оказывается противоположным исходному: главная часть обозначает причину, основание, а придаточная - следствие, вывод.

Comment: Элен, прочитайте комментарии Ларf ниже. Запятую, я думаю, надо ставить.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, здесь можно бы трактовать как составной союз "Если ..., значит ...". 
"Значит" здесь выступает вместо "то", а не "следовательно".

Хотя реально таких примеров (без обособления) я не нашёл даже в нацкорпусе, поэтому снимаю предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько важен здесь союз "если"? Про тебя идут слухи, значит (,) ты личность.

И ещё с "Грамоты": ЗНАЧИТ, вводное слово, союз и связка

1. Вводное слово. Указывает на связь мыслей, последовательность их изложения; то же, что «стало быть, выходит, следовательно». Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях см. в Прил. 2.

Село, значит, наше – Радово, // Дворов, почитай, два ста. С. Есенин, Анна Снегина. «Здравствуй, здравствуй, внучек, – произнесла она неожиданно звучным басом. – Это, значит, и будет новый программист?» А. и Б. Стругацкие, Понедельник начинается в субботу. Перед уходом я достал из-под стекла список и предельным нажимом вымарал слово «Волобуй» своей радужной ручкой. Я решился на это потому, что оно лохматилось бумажными ворсинками и, значит, его уже царапали до меня когтем… К. Воробьев, Вот пришел великан. Случайно появляется газ или нет, связан ли он с циклонами, а значит, можно ли по этому признаку прогнозировать – вопрос требует выяснения. А. Гладилин, Прогноз на завтра. Собираешься, значит, уезжать? Ты, значит, думаешь иначе?

1. Союз. Соединяет предложения или части сложного предложения  (в том числе в составе двойного союза «если... значит» или «раз... значит»). Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», **союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения.**

Мы договорились расплачиваться по окончании игры, но, если дело и дальше так пойдет, моих денег уже очень скоро не хватит, их у меня чуть больше рубля. Значит, за рубль переваливать нельзя... В. Распутин, Уроки французского. **Послал он мне крест – значит, меня он любит.** И. Тургенев, Живые мощи. У меня так было с сыном. Тоже думали, что погиб, а он лежал в госпитале. А сейчас прыгает без ноги, но – дома, в армию его не взяли, значит, будет жить. Ю. Семенов, Семнадцать мгновений весны. **А если он в таком состоянии, что и чинить нельзя, значит, надо выбросить.** В. Войнович, Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина. Раз эсер, то, значит, безгрешен! Ю. Семенов, Непримиримость. **Раз вы читаете это мое письмецо, значит, я вас уже покинул и познал тайну смерти, которая сокрыта от вас за семью печатями.** Б. Акунин, Азазель. Идя коридором своего отеля, он заглянул в комнату дежурной горничной, комната была пуста, значит – девушка не спит еще. М. Горький, Жизнь Клима Самгина.

1. Связка (при сказуемом, выраженном инфинитивом). То же, что «это, есть». Перед связкой «значит», присоединяющей сказуемое к подлежащему, ставится тире. После связки знак препинания не ставится.

В свете идти на любовь – значит идти на верный обман. В. Соллогуб, Метель. У Шекспира есть выражение: понять – значит простить. М. Анчаров, Сода-солнце. Идти обратно вдоль реки, чтоб наткнуться на знакомую тропу, которая ведет в сосновый бор, – значит потерять день. В. Тендряков, Находка.

**Получается, союз это или вводное слово (в обоих случаях, по Ожегову, возможна замена на "следовательно" ) - чисто теоретический интерес. Запятая ставится после слова "значит"  любом случае.**

Но вот у Лопатина:На небе собираются тучи, **значит** будет дождь (**значит — союз)**.

Кто прав? Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста. (Я до сегодняшнего обсуждения ставила бы запятую и ни в какой справочник бы не заглядывала. А вот теперь и не знаю...)

Comment: Ларf, я тоже поставила бы запятую после слова "значит" в предложении "На небе собираются тучи, значит будет дождь". Видела, как и Вы,  это у Лопатина. Объяснить отсутствие запятой можно, наверное,  тем, что "значит" здесь заменяет союз "так что". Но у Розенталя как-то нашла, что в БСП, на стыке частей с\п, после слова "значит" запятая ставится. "Значит" = "следовательно", вводное слово.  Ни разу не встречала подобного примера без запятой, обычно я обращаю внимание на такие вещи. Никогда не видела союза "значит": средство связи, связка - видела, но союз...

Comment: Начиталась о слове "значит" много чего. Категорически не согласна, что "значит" может быть союзом. В составе союзного соединения - да, и то с оговоркой, что одна часть в этом соединении собственно союз (если, например), а другая так называемый "коррелят" (значит). А в примере с "Грамоты" (Послал он мне крест – значит, меня он любит.)как раз коррелят, а не союз. Союз ЕСЛИ или РАЗ выпущен. Запятая, конечно же, нужна.

Comment: "На небе собираются тучи, значит будет дождь". Запятой здесь явно не хватает. Хотя ещё в советское время (когда безграмотных написаний в печатной продукции не было) я заметила именно со "значит": ну не всегда запятая стояла, хотя правила этого требовали. Примеров сейчас, конечно, не приведу. Но вот эти мучения со "значит" запомнились. А что это союз... Как-то странно.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь:  
http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5315&0a0=1831#3017  
На "СЛОВАРИ.РУ" о сочетании "если...значит" рассказывают минимум два параграфа-3017 и 3018. Эх! Учиться никогда не поздно...

Comment: Вы даете ссылку на "Грамматику-80". Это хорошее фундаментальное научное издание, и когда я нигде не могла найти информацию, я всегда вспоминала об этом издании. К счастью, не так давно тоже нашла онлайн-издание. Но надо иметь в виду, что это не истина в последней инстанции, а всего лишь мнение некоторой части лингвистов на момент составления "Грамматики" (1980 г.) Я училась в университете, когда это издание было только только что вышедшим. А до этого была "Грамматика _70".

Comment: ТАк вот я помню (а среди наших преподавателей был и автор некоторых статей "Гр.-80), что не только по некоторым позициям  расходились мнения этих "Грамматик", но и авторы некоторых статей в "ГР.-80" критически были настроены по отношению к другим статьям. Это безотносительно к слову "значит". Это для сведения и по поводу восторга от источника.

Comment: И ещё. Не случайно Элен не поняла про запятые, "Грамматика" описывает грамматический строй языка (морфологию и синтаксис), прикладными разделами (орфографией и пунктуацией) не занимается.

Comment: Спасибо, Ларf, огромное! Я понимаю, что лингвисты спорили, спорят и будут спорить всегда, это нормально. По этой причине и я, например,  не могу найти точный  ответ на многие вопросы с университетских времён. Бывает ли категория состояния подлежащим? Какой морфемой считать -ть в инфинитиве? Является ли Ы фонемой? Как правильно: Ибо или ибО? И т.д. Спорят. Язык развивается, даже нормы приходится менять.  Пунктуацию этого предложения мы, мне кажется, верно определили. "Значит" выделяем по двум критериям (с опорой на Розенталя). Но тема и в самом деле интересная.

Comment: Говорят, формат форума не предусматривает дискуссий. Мне хочется ответить на один из Ваших вопросов. Про категорию состояния. Задайте его в виде отдельного вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, "ЗНАЧИТ" является вводным, если оно может быть заменено словами "следовательно", "стало быть" : Сообщение важное, значит, его нужно передать сегодня.   Это слово может оказаться сказуемым, близким по смыслу к "означает" : Собака значит для него больше, чем жена. Когда по-настоящему дружишь с человеком, это значит, что ему во всем доверяешь. "Значит" может оказаться между подлежащим и сказуемым, особенно когда они выражены инфинитивами. В этом случае перед "значит" ставится тире : Обижаться – значит признавать себя слабым.
Мне кажется, наше предложение аналогично данному: Когда по-настоящему дружишь с человеком, это значит, что ему во всем доверяешь.